# Word 2007 jumplist missing

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2007, jumplist

For some reason the jumplist showing recent documents on my pc has gone.  The link is still pinned to the taskbar but the list shows no documents.

How can I get the jumplist to show recent documents?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: The recently used list can become [too large, or corrupted](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/22202-problem-jump-list-fails-work.html#post557602). Go to the folder at:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
```

and delete any suspiciously large files. For example, I deleted a 175kB file, and now Firefox lists recently opened web pages in its jump list.

---

Right click on the taskbar. In `Start Menu > Privacy` make sure that `Store and display recently opened items in the Start menu and the taskbar` is checked:

[image: jump list recent items]

Comment: Yeah, they are already checked.  Excel, IE etc are all showing their jumplists correctly.

Comment: Thanks, the deleting of the large file worked fine!  I had one that was nearly 3MB!

Comment: Thx a lot, works also when Windows Explorer is missing its Jump List