# Losing recent files in Windows 7 Taskbar Jump List

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010, jumplist

I have some applications pinned to my Taskbar and I use the Jump List to open recent solutions.  The Jump List keeps resetting itself, removing both the pinned item and the unpinned.

This seems to be only affecting "document-centric" applications that I have pinned.  These show a list of files recently opened by the application and allow you to "pin" the file.  The application affected are Visual Studio 2010 and FinalBuilder.

Is there any way I can fix this?  Being able to back up and restore the Jump List contents would be useful if I can't stop it happening.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Word 2007 jumplist missing](http://superuser.com/questions/106629/word-2007-jumplist-missing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jump "Frequent" lists are not perfect and can become corrupted.

Navigate to this folder and delete everything in there to start fresh. This will clean out "frequent" items.

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
```

You can edit individual items in this folder:
you will see a list of files with very long and convoluted names. This is because they are all encoded. Each one represents a list of recent items for a particular jumplist.

It’s impossible to tell which entries go with which jumplists unless you open the file in a text editor and browse through.

[Source of Information](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-7/clear-recent-items-windows-7-jumplists/)

Comment: Thanks Moab.  Your linked article has a link to a little app that lets you create custom jump lists.  Just what I needed, many thanks!

Comment: Which led me to this article about another Jump List extender tool: http://www.nirmaltv.com/2011/05/23/add-custom-jumlists-to-any-program-with-jumplist-extender/.  I'm using that one for now as it seems more flexible.

Comment: You can use Jump List View from Nirsoft http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/jump_lists_view.html, it shows the Jump List entries quite nicely