# My Pinned List In Excel Is Gone

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

My pinned files from Excel are gone
I have tried to go here:
`APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`
But I have no idea what to do there. Can someone please help me get them back. 
If I `right click start` and then go to `Properties` then the `start menu tab`, the correct boxes ARE checked.

Comment: Try [I had files pinned to my Excel task bar icon but now they are missing & I cannot pin any files. What happened?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/i-had-files-pinned-to-my-excel-task-bar-icon-but/5cc8900e-c365-41b0-ad30-6bfb014a7a4a?msgId=370cf639-1bbc-4e2b-9f52-75aab4efb882)

Comment: Does this help: [Word 2007 jumplist missing](http://superuser.com/a/106634/494)

Answer (score 1):

From comments under the OP suggested by sblair and Tony, you should look for the largest files in the folder and delete those. For example all the files in this folder on my computer are under 50K so anything larger than 1MB or even close to it is probably a corrupt file.

Links from comments above:

[Word 2007 jumplist missing](https://superuser.com/questions/106629/word-2007-jumplist-missing/106634#106634)

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/i-had-files-pinned-to-my-excel-task-bar-icon-but/5cc8900e-c365-41b0-ad30-6bfb014a7a4a?msgId=370cf639-1bbc-4e2b-9f52-75aab4efb882

and another thread on the Microsoft answer site with a similar suggestion (among others) and some background info.
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/i-had-files-pinned-to-my-excel-task-bar-icon-but/5cc8900e-c365-41b0-ad30-6bfb014a7a4a

Deleting the abnormally large files in this folder seems to have the best success rate. Note that this will delete all of the pinned items for the associated program. If you delete all the files in this folder it will delete all of the recent or pinned items for all programs.

The answer on this page tells you which files to delete for Word or Excel jump lists:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/jump-list-recent-documents-missing-from-jumplist/cd9a9052-1d8e-4a6c-9e45-46d9dc171d7c

In step 4 from that page:

4. Locate the following file.

For Word 2010:  a7bd71699cd38d1c.automaticDestinations-ms

For Word 2007:   adecfb853d77462a.automaticDestinations-ms

And the corresponding registry entries can be found here:

"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\User MRU"

as per this answer:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/where-are-pinned-documents-stored-in-office-2013/b10a9335-3f0e-4f24-aeb1-bb86a5183c67