# Excel workbooks pinned to taskbar on Win 10 disappeared

Tags: microsoft-excel, taskbar, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

My question is two fold:

1. Can I change the order of Excel workbooks pinned to the taskbar on Win 10? In Win 8.1 I could just drag them in whichever order I wanted.
   I saw the similar question regarding folders pinned to File Explorer, but the solution is irrelevant in this case.
   The question regarding Excel was also raised there in a comment but remained  unanswered.

Edit: Here's the link to the question I reffered to:
[Is there a way to change the order of pinned folders in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/950261/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-order-of-pinned-folders-in-windows-10)

2. When I upgraded to Win 10 from Win 8.1 all my pinned Excel workbooks stayed pinned. After a couple of day's work they all disappeared. I can't put my finger exactly on when this happened but my best guesstimate is either from running Ccleaner or when I restarted the computer for the first time after the upgrade was complete.
   Anyone else encountered something similar?

Thanks.

Comment: With regard to your second question (and perhaps this question should be split into two questions) see http://superuser.com/questions/380674/my-pinned-list-in-excel-is-gone\